# get unique results from (get-help computer).moduleName

Tags: powershell

I try to get the unique modules as:

```
 ~ λ get-help computer | select -property moduleName  -unique

ModuleName
----------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
oh-my-posh
ActiveDirectory
ConfigDefender
```

Then I get property alternatively as :

```
 ~ λ (get-help computer).moduleName                                                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
oh-my-posh
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ActiveDirectory
ConfigDefender
```

How could I a unique result?

Answer (score 4):

You've got at least 3 options:

```
$x = (get-help computer).moduleName

$x | select-object -Unique

$x | sort-object -Unique

$x | Get-Unique
```

**Select-Object**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1

> -Unique
>
> Specifies that if a subset of the input objects has identical properties and values, only a single member of the subset will be selected.
>
> This parameter is case-sensitive. As a result, strings that differ only in character casing are considered to be unique.

**Sort-Object**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1

> -Unique
>
> Indicates that Sort-Object eliminates duplicates and returns only the unique members of the collection. The first instance of a unique value is included in the sorted output.
>
> Unique is case-insensitive. Strings that only differ by character case are considered the same. For example, character and CHARACTER.

**Get-Unique**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique?view=powershell-7.1

> The Get-Unique cmdlet compares each item in a sorted list to the next item, eliminates duplicates, and returns only one instance of each item. The list must be sorted for the cmdlet to work properly.
>
> Get-Unique is case-sensitive. As a result, strings that differ only in character casing are considered to be unique.